# Python pandas combine data within a table (date into week/month)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: amerika2 defined]

I have a huge dataset available where all days since the corona pandemic within america have been documented. (i work with Pandas in Python)

I now want to achieve the following:

All days of a state should be summarized with the whole number of new_results_reported.
then a function should merge the data to weeks or months, so that i can display e.g. all positive outcomes of alabama in one month.

[image: code preview]

datatype of each column:

```
state_name                object
overall_outcome           object
date                      object
new_results_reported       int64
total_results_reported     int64
dtype: object
```

[image: Preview with all columns]

Comment: It's recommended to add your data as plain text, we can not copy the contents from image. Please take a look at [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can say

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)
df['Week'] = df['date'].dt.week
df['Month'] = df['date'].dt.month
df.groupby(['Month'], as_index=False)[['total_results_reported']].sum()
```

Comment: hey thanks for ur answer if i try it it says :NameError: name 'Amerika2' is not defined

Comment: can you share the code ? since it looks variable issue

Comment: I think you don't have Amerika data frame defined above

Comment: i did defined it i posted it as screen above

Comment: I think if you apply pd to datetime method Amerika2, it will be totally ok.

Comment: sorry i dont unerstand what u mean with that